# How to Intercept response data of redirect link(301,302) use cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

all.

I used cefsharp  IRequestHandler.GetResourceResponseFilter to intercept response data. i need the response html to do samething.

If the link response StatusCode==200, i can get the response html. but when the link StatusCode==30x,i can not intercept reponse data.

i used cefsharp v65. winform .

The code:

```
public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
{
      LogHelper.log("", "----GetResourceResponseFilter:" + request.Url+":" + response.StatusCode+":"+response.StatusText+":"); 

      do same work.
}
```

I reocde all request.Url, but the link of 30x not in it.

mybe IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter can not intercept link which StatusCode not 200;

so, how to get the response html of a 30x link?

Thanks.

Comment: Redirects are handled using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnResourceRedirect.htm in most cases a redirect only has a Location header and no actual response data.

Comment: Thank you, that solved this problem, the response data == the Location value.